# Safari on iOS 9 does not trigger click event on hidden input file

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, mobile-safari, ios9

I have a website with an upload field, but the `input` is hidden with `display: none;` and I have a `div` for calling this action.

It worked on iOS 8, but now after the iOS 9 update, nothing happens when I touch in the div.

I've tried using the `[0].click()` or pure VanillaJS like `document.getElementById('file_input').click()` and nothing works.

All these methods work between iOS 5 and iOS 8.

**If you want, link to this example on JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/o1r265tz/6/embedded/result/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('click touchstart', '.upload-box', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.form-upload input.file-input').trigger('click');

    $('.debug').append('<p>Clicked!</p>');
    console.log('Clicked!');
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.upload-box {
  border: 3px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 35pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #555;
}
.form-upload {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upload-box">Click here to upload =D</div>

<form class="form-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input class="file-input" id="file_input" type="file">
</form>

<div class="debug"></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three things are causing this problem:

1. At javascript, removing `return false;` of the event listener.
2. At the stylesheet, the element which calls the action must have the property `cursor: pointer;`. Probably Apple put this requirement in these calls for best feedback on a user interface.
3. Again at the stylesheet, we can't set `display: none;` for hidden input because some browsers don't accept clicks on elements that aren't displayed.

[Link to a fixed example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2udcqxz/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: same problem . i removed display none and made cursor to pointer for input type file . nothing happening in ios :( :(

Answer (score 1):

Putting the `<input type="file"/>` on top of the fake button with `position: absolute` and `opacity: 0` works. You might also need to set the correct z-index and make the input 100% width and height so it catches the click on top of the button.

Source: https://forums.meteor.com/t/webkit-on-ios-ignores-trigger-click-on-file-input/29828

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `touchstart` event from JS file or replace it with `mousedown` event.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.upload-box', function(e){
  ...
});
```

Comment: The problem is not on event handling, and the correct trigger is touchstart. The problem occurs when you try to do .click() on input file field inside the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently it's JUST a jQuery thing. This page shows that it can work.

https://codepen.io/VincentBel/pen/wqQOGr

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file" style='display:none'/>
<button id="button" type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click()">trigger file selection</button>
```