# onclick event doesn't work on iphone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iphone

I have form which should upload image. each form placed in iframe

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; cursor: pointer;" onclick="document.querySelector('.register-upload-input').click()">
   <form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/de/client/registerupload" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input class="register-upload-input" style="display: none;" onchange="document.querySelector(".preloader").style.display="block";document.querySelector("form").submit();" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" name="image" type="file">
   </form>
</body
```

so I click on iframe, file upload dialog appears and I can choose image. `body` element has `onclick` event.
everything works fine, but when I try to upload images with iphone nothing happens, dialog prompt dosn't show up. it works on android, but doesn't work on iphone. I did research, usually such problem happens cause the element should has `cursor: pointer` in styles. I added it, but nothings changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set `display:none` on `<input>`,you can set `height:0px` instead.

**EDIT:**

I checked my note, find that there has been a same question on stackoverflow.

the same question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708496/safari-on-ios-9-does-not-trigger-click-event-on-hidden-input-file).

> Three things are causing this problem:
>
> 1. At javascript, removing return false; of event listener.
> 2. At the stylesheet, the element which calls the action must have the property
>    cursor: pointer;. Probably Apple put this requirement in these calls
>    for best feedback on user interface.
> 3. Again at the stylesheet, we can't
>    setting display: none; for hidden input because some browsers don't
>    accept clicks on elements that aren't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following CSS to the **IFrame** content.

```
html, body {
    touch-action: auto;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I added this style, but still not working