# why window doesn't fire click event for touch device

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a [demo link](http://click.surge.sh/) that I want to add `click` event for window. It works fine for desktop but not for mobile.

Basically I run tests on lastest Chrome and Safari,

```
  $('#button1').click(function(){
     $('#text').append('<div> jquery click</div>')
     // this would get executed on both desktop and mobile
  })
    window.addEventListener('click', function() {
     $('#text').append('<div> native click on window</div>')
     // this only gets executed on desktop
  })
```

So my question is, why the `click` event doesn't fire when on mobile?

Comment: These are all very generic statements ...  Please include the **code** for which the `click` events are not happening .. Examples of what works in what browser etc etc ..

Comment: Can you click a screen? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safari on iOS 9 does not trigger click event on hidden input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708496/safari-on-ios-9-does-not-trigger-click-event-on-hidden-input-file)

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Can you remove the "possible answered question" please? It's not a similar question,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Browser_compatibility) shows that for Safari, if an element is not considered 'clickable', no click event would fire. I would assume that `window` is not considered 'clickable' so no 'click' event would fire by `window` (except the ones propagated by other clickable elements).

There is also a Safari [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW7) to explains this.

Though I didn't find anything on Chrome,  I would assume since it adopts the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Safari doesn't consider the window a clickable event.

As ydydyd pointed out, the [Safari docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW7) goes into a more detailed explanation.

To fix it, simply replace `window.addEventListener()` with `document.addEventListener()`